# REGEXMATCH and MATCH don't work when a cell contains a number

Tags: regex, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to use formulas to find a row in my google spreadsheet document, however I have got a weird problem.

I am not able to find values when a cell contains a number (without any other characters).

Consider the following case

I have got two values

```
A1 - 32323232323
A2 - 323-23232-323
```

When I use the following formula

```
=FILTER(A:E,REGEXMATCH(B:B,"323-23232-323"))
```

It works fine, it successfully finds A2 value, however when I try to use the following formula

```
=FILTER(A:E,REGEXMATCH(B:B,"32323232323"))
```

It doesn't match any row, and I also tried the following formula

```
ADDRESS(MATCH("32323232323",B:B,0),1)
```

It doesn't work either, it only works when I remove quotes like that

```
ADDRESS(MATCH(32323232323,B:B,0),1)
```

But this doesn't work with `REGEXMATCH`.

Is there any way I can match numbers using a regex expression (exact number, without wildcards) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=FILTER(A:A,REGEXMATCH(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(A:A),"-",""), "32323232323"))`

- to get both 323-23232-323 and 32323232323.

`=FILTER(A:E,REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(B:B),"32323232323"))`

- to get number 32323232323.

Notes:

- Converting `to_text` is a key here.
- Change columns to yours.

Comment: Thank for your answer, please change your answer to this one `=FILTER(A:E,REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(B:B),"32323232323"))` that is exactly the formula I was looking for